# C++/CLI 0xC0020001: "The string binding is invalid" at application exit

Tags: c#, c++

I'm wrapping a C++ library with C++/CLI in order to use it from C#.
For now I have a simple Winform with two buttons:

One button just makes a

```
MyWrapperClass data = new MyWrapperClass()
```

The other button does the following:

```
OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();

if(dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
  MyWrapperClass data = new MyWrapperClass()
}
```

If I push the first button and then close the application, I get the exception

0xC0020001: "The string binding is invalid"

If I push the second button (which opens a FileDialog) and then close the application, I have no problems.

When the app crashes Visual Studio opens the file

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\crt\src\vcruntime\utility.cpp

```
at line 395: _execute_onexit_table(&module_local_atexit_table);
```

the exceptiont seems to appen at that line.

Thanks for any help

EDIT: This is basically what I do inside the MyWrapperClass

```
public ref class MyWrapperClass{

public:
  MyWrapperClass(){
    native_class = new NativeClass();
  }

  ~MyWrapperClass(){
    this->!MyWrapperClass();
  }

  !MyWrapperClass(){
    delete native_class;
  }

private:
  NativeClass * native_class;
}
```

Comment: It is the exception you get at program termination when managed code runs *after* support for managed code execution is already cleaned-up and disabled.  Hard to debug because the stack trace is not very useful.  And you didn't give us anything to look at, a snippet is only useful if it provides a repro.  Compiling too much native C++ with /clr in effect tends to be the underlying problem.  So be sure to segregate it well enough, moving such code in a library project tends to help.  And comment out chunks of code to find the troublemaker, be wary of global variables with a destructor.

Comment: It looks like the issue is a stack mis-alignment.  The variable sizes are not the same from the parent and the child (or the return parameter).  In old c language programs integers were only 16 bits instead of 32 bits.  Also check you project settings to make sure you are using x86 option.